# Weighted average for every possible range

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm looking for the averages of column 'Score' 
weighted by 'Weight' for all the subranges :  rows 0-1, 0-2 ...., 1-2, 1-3..., 2-3, 2-4.... ,  etc.

The expected result would be the subrange(s) with the highest average.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Weight': (2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'Score': (6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9)})

print(df2)

   Score  Weight
0      6       2
1      7       3
2      8       4
3      9       5
4      6       2
5      7       3
6      8       4
7      9       5
```

Comment: @Zanshin: not my downvote, but the downvote criteria shown when you hover over the button include "does not show any research effort" and "is unclear".  Your question shows no effort toward a solution, and you don't bother to show what numbers you expect to get for that sample, even after being requested to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list or generator expressions here (prefer the latter).

- **First**, generate all possible ranges using two loops to define start and end ranges.
- **Second**, generate all averages using the the generated indices.
- **Finally**, get the range with the highest average:

See below:

```
# create column with weighted scores
df2["Weighted"] = df2["Score"] * df2["Weight"]

# create helper function for averaging
average = lambda indices: df2.loc[indices, "Weighted"].mean()

# generate all possible ranges
length = df2.shape[0] + 1 
ranges = (range(start, end)
          for start in range(length) 
          for end in range(start + 1, length))

# generate all averages
averages = ((indices, average(indices)) for indices in ranges)

# get highest average with value
high_range, high_value = max(averages, key=lambda x: x[1])

# show result
print("Range:", list(high_range), "Avg:", high_value)
Range: [3] Avg: 45.0
```

Be aware that you need a sorted integer index starting with 0 for your data frame. Otherwise, this solution won't work because it explodes the structure of the index using `range`.

To explain it a bit in more detail. Take a close look at the generated ranges here:

```
ranges = (range(start, end)
          for start in range(length) 
          for end in range(start + 1, length))
print([list(x) for x in ranges])

[[0],
 [0, 1],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [2],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [3],
 [3, 4],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [4],
 [4, 5],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 5, 6, 7],
 [5],
 [5, 6],
 [5, 6, 7],
 [6],
 [6, 7],
 [7]]
```

And also at the averages:

```
ranges = (range(start, end)
          for start in range(length) 
          for end in range(start + 1, length))
averages = ((indices, average(indices)) for indices in ranges)
print([list(x) for x in averages])

[[range(0, 1), 12.0],
 [range(0, 2), 16.5],
 [range(0, 3), 21.666666666666668],
 [range(0, 4), 27.5],
 [range(0, 5), 24.399999999999999],
 [range(0, 6), 23.833333333333332],
 [range(0, 7), 25.0],
 [range(0, 8), 27.5],
 [range(1, 2), 21.0],
 [range(1, 3), 26.5],
 [range(1, 4), 32.666666666666664],
 [range(1, 5), 27.5],
 [range(1, 6), 26.199999999999999],
 [range(1, 7), 27.166666666666668],
 [range(1, 8), 29.714285714285715],
 [range(2, 3), 32.0],
 [range(2, 4), 38.5],
 [range(2, 5), 29.666666666666668],
 [range(2, 6), 27.5],
 [range(2, 7), 28.399999999999999],
 [range(2, 8), 31.166666666666668],
 [range(3, 4), 45.0],
 [range(3, 5), 28.5],
 [range(3, 6), 26.0],
 [range(3, 7), 27.5],
 [range(3, 8), 31.0],
 [range(4, 5), 12.0],
 [range(4, 6), 16.5],
 [range(4, 7), 21.666666666666668],
 [range(4, 8), 27.5],
 [range(5, 6), 21.0],
 [range(5, 7), 26.5],
 [range(5, 8), 32.666666666666664],
 [range(6, 7), 32.0],
 [range(6, 8), 38.5],
 [range(7, 8), 45.0]]
```

#### Edit: multiple max ranges

To get all maximum ranges (not just one), you need to slightly modify the code. Because we have to iterate twice over `averages` (first find the max average, then compare each average with max average) , I turned it into a list comprehension.

```
# generate all averages
averages = [(indices, df2.loc[indices, "Weighted"].mean()) 
            for indices in ranges]

max_average = max(averages, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
highest = [tuples for tuples in averages if tuples[1] == max_average]

print(highest)
[(range(3, 4), 45.0), (range(7, 8), 45.0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I see there is another range with 45.0. how might we solve that ? Can both be returned?

Comment: @Zanshin See updated answer.

Comment: @Zanshin Can you please update your question description to provide future readers with a better understanding of your desired outcome? It was also not exactly clear to me.

Comment: Edited per request

Comment: could we add a minimum range as well?